# Shutdown Lubuntu

Tags: shutdown

Since installing Ubuntu 12.04 and now Lubuntu 14.04 I cannot power off machine unless done manually.  I have searched the forums and tried every "sudo" command mentioned, none of them work. Shutdown begins and then hangs is splash screen and must be powered off with button. I did get a "no kernel" message once and never showed up again. Again I have tried all the "shudo shutdown/ sudo halt/ blah blah blah I found in the forums, nothing works. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown -h now` and leaving it alone?

Comment: What error do you get when you shutdown lubuntu from Menu > logout > shutdown? Or doesn't it do anything?

Comment: Yes I have tried "sudo  shutdown -h"  It starts normal shutdown but then hangs at splash screen, no power off.

Comment: When I type "sudo shutdown -h now"  I get " wait-for-state stop/waiting stoping rsync daemon rsync asking all remaining processes to terminate...all processes ended within 1 seconds...ModemManager[599]: <info> ModemManager is shutdown Deactivating swap....Will now halt 147.8594271 reboot: System halted"  And just hangs with no power off.

Comment: Also get this sometimes  "power manager, kernel not supported."